# import files from same directory in VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm unable to import a .py file into another .py file. I thought things would be easy just by doing

```
import filename.py
```

but I always get a ModuleNotFoundError

I've also tried :

```
from .filename import *
```

```
from filename import *
```

```
from .filename import Class
```

```
from . import filename
```

I've also tried to add

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
```

But that didn't work as well.

Would you guys see what I would be missing ?

Just to clarify :

- I'm using Python3 on VSCode
- Both my files are in the same directory.

Here is the structure

```
.
├── __pycache__
│   └── model.cpython-36.pyc
├── ai.py
├── model.py
└── recording
    ├── openaigym.video.0.2641.video000000.meta.json
    └── openaigym.video.0.2641.video000000.mp4
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Sometimes (or always) modules are searched from the location of the main file. So you need to make the path relative to that and this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?rq=1

Comment: Can you give a tree structure of your module and main file?

Comment: Could you provide the command being run in the terminal and show the folder structure?

Comment: To be clearer, I have two files, both in the same directory. I edited the question to provide the folder structure. 

I'm trying to import model.py into ai.py 

I'm using an Interactive Notebook on VSCode, so I'm running each part of my code as if it was a cell. 

I tried to simply do 

`python ai.py`

but I get the same error

Comment: You shouldn't need the `.py` on the `import`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen if your class name clashes with any of the existing python class

In your `ai.py` file do:

```py
from model import Class_name
```

If even this doesn't work, add an empty `__init__.py` file in the same directory where you have `model.py` and `ai.py`.

Note: Sometimes VSCode displays `unresolved imports` warning even though your code works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @saintlyzero. Indeed, it works ! I also found that actually simply restarting the kernel in VSCode makes it work.